# how to add freindly URL for a page with 2 parameters in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I am implementing Eastern Bank payment gateway in PrestaShop 1.6. I have configured the callback URLs for successful payment and payment cancel.
My payment controller is as follows:

```js
class EblpaymentPaymentModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public $ssl = true;

    /**
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
    }
    $this->setTemplate('ebl_payment.tpl');
}
```

ebl_payment.tpl is as follows:

```js
<script src= "https:easterbank-test-server/checkout.js"
data-complete="http://localhost/modules/eblpayment/eblcallback"
data-cancel="http://localhost/modules/eblpayment/eblcallback"
>
<input type="button" name="paymentSubmit" onclick="Checkout.showPaymentPage();" value="Submit Order" class="exclusive_large"/>
```

When I click on the button in ebl_payment.tpl I am redirected to payment page.
[image]

then after successful payment I am redirected to the following URL:

> http://localhost/modules/eblpayment/eblcallback?resultIndicator=3496c5ca27314c6f&sessionVersion=35ae276406

For this URL I get 404 page.

I can add a Friendly URL for a front controller page in back office under SEO & URLS section.

Now I want to add Friendly URL for the above URL with two tailing parameters "resultIndicator" and "sessionVersion" so that I can redirect to the "eblcallback" front controller URL as given as data-complete value in ebl_payment.tpl page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for the problem.
Just changing the callback URL

> http://localhost/modules/eblpayment/eblcallback

to

> http://localhost/index.php?fc=module&module=eblpayment&controller=eblcallback'

resolved the issue.

I am redirected to "eblcallback" front controller. 
Here I can fetch the URL parameters by Tools::getValue('resultIndicator') and then check for desired result "payment success" or "payment failed" etc.

No need to add Friendly URL.